# react-select background color issues

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Having a problem with using className prop.
What's happening for me is that only the parent div gets the class and the children divs don't. As a result, they end up having background color white instead of the override color.

```
<Select
    className="games-dropdown-2"
    defaultValue={colourOptions[0]}
    name="color"
    options={colourOptions}
/>
```

Below is the css class

```
.games-dropdown-2 {
  background-color: #023950;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 93%;
}
```

Another problem is that the child div seems to be inheriting border css from the grandparent div which is weird.

Attaching an image to give idea.
[react-select-classname-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGbq0.png)

Comment: Which version of react-select are you using ? v1 or v2 ?

Comment: package.json says "react-select": "^2.0.0" so v2.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot so I'll be sure that I'm seeing the same problem as you ? I think I have the answer

Comment: I already have it attached. Just click on the link above that says 'Attaching an image to give an idea.'

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For v2 it's way easier to use style-in-JS in order to customize your select. So in your case you can try something like this:

```
const customStyles = {
  control: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    background: "#023950",
    // match with the menu
    borderRadius: state.isFocused ? "3px 3px 0 0" : 3,
    // Overwrittes the different states of border
    borderColor: state.isFocused ? "yellow" : "green",
    // Removes weird border around container
    boxShadow: state.isFocused ? null : null,
    "&:hover": {
      // Overwrittes the different states of border
      borderColor: state.isFocused ? "red" : "blue"
    }
  }),
  menu: base => ({
    ...base,
    // override border radius to match the box
    borderRadius: 0,
    // kill the gap
    marginTop: 0
  }),
  menuList: base => ({
    ...base,
    // kill the white space on first and last option
    padding: 0
  })
};

<Select styles={customStyles} options={options} />
```

[image]
If you need to use thus select in different files I would recommend to create a custom component so you won't have to repeat the style everywhere.

By default the text will take the color define in your general CSS file.

[Here the live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jv6xpr2q3).

### UPDATE

Following your request in comment I have updated the code above and [here a new live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9422zoz33w).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the live example. Yes I did try that as well and ran into another set of issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760037/react-select-styling-issues-with-style-props

I will give your example a whirl. By any chance, would you know the answer to these 2 things

1. How to get rid of that gap between the dropdown and it's options there?
2. There is also a white gap on top of option 1 and below option 5. How to get rid of that. Basically just get a flat rectangle box. I have more details in that other post too.

Comment: @user3267324 I have updated my example, I hope that it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I will give this a shot :D

Answer (score 3):

you can solve your background color issue like below and people have also faced some issue of z-index that also solved

```
const colourStyles = {
menuList: styles => ({
    ...styles,
    background: 'papayawhip'
}),
option: (styles, {isFocused, isSelected}) => ({
    ...styles,
    background: isFocused
        ? 'hsla(291, 64%, 42%, 0.5)'
        : isSelected
            ? 'hsla(291, 64%, 42%, 1)'
            : undefined,
    zIndex: 1
}),
menu: base => ({
    ...base,
    zIndex: 100
})
}

    const options = [
    {value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate'},
    {value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry'},
    ]

<Select
   // defaultValue={[colourOptions[2], colourOptions[3]]}
      name="colors"
      options={options}
      className="basic-multi-select"
      classNamePrefix="select"
      styles={colourStyles}
   />
```