# React-select: background color does not fill full width on wordWrap:"scroll"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, react-select

I am trying use react-select in one of my projects. The **wordWrap** needs to be **"scroll"**. However, if the option length exceeds the width of the menu and if I scroll to the right, the hover color does not fill to the full width.

[image]

Following is the code for reference. Taken from https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-curie-etoj3 with some modifications.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const customStyles = {
    control: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
      width: 300,
      background: "#023950",
      // match with the menu
      borderRadius: state.isFocused ? "3px 3px 0 0" : 3,
      // Overwrittes the different states of border
      borderColor: state.isFocused ? "yellow" : "green",
      // Removes weird border around container
      boxShadow: state.isFocused ? null : null,
      "&:hover": {
        // Overwrittes the different states of border
        borderColor: state.isFocused ? "red" : "blue"
      }
    }),
    menu: base => ({
      ...base,
      width: 300,
      // override border radius to match the box
      borderRadius: 0,
      // beautify the word cut by adding a dash see https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens for the compatibility
      hyphens: "auto",
      // kill the gap
      marginTop: 0,
      textAlign: "left",
      // prevent menu to scroll y
      wordWrap: "normal"
    }),
    menuList: base => ({
      ...base,
      // kill the white space on first and last option
      padding: 0
    })
  };

  const options = [
    {
      label: "option 1 akjbalskej",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      label: "option 2 akjbalskej",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      label: "option 3 akjbalskej",
      value: 3
    },
    {
      label: "option 4 akjbalskej",
      value: 4
    },
    {
      label: "option 5 akjbalskej",
      value: 5
    },
    {
      label:
        "supercalifragilisticexpialidocioussupercalifragilisticexpialidocioussupercalifragilisticexpialidocious",
      value: 6
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select styles={customStyles} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I am fairly new to react and frontend development. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fixed the problem? cause the codesandbox was ok (but it had a syntax problem.)

Comment: Not yet. Do you have a solution? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The thing is that css word-wrap takes only 2 property: 'normal' and 'break-word', so 'scroll' is not valid for it.

Comment: @VahidAl same result for "normal" too.

Comment: Try my answer, does it work for you?

Comment: @VahidAl, I'm afraid not. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194886/discussion-between-mahesh-nepal-and-vahid-al).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-select styling issues with style props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760037/react-select-styling-issues-with-style-props)

Answer (score 0):

You should use text-overflow, white-space and overflow instead of word-wrap:
Change your `menu` object to this:

```
menu: base => ({
  ...
  // wordWrap: "normal",
  whiteSpace: "nowrap",
  overflow: "hidden",
  textOverflow: "ellipsis"
}),
```

Comment: This does partially solve the problem, however, the options are not fully visible.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been evoked in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760037/react-select-styling-issues-with-style-props) by an other user.

Change your `wordWrap: 'normal'` for `wordWrap: 'break-word'` like in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/jj3r81l3.

Full style props:

```
const customStyles = {
    control: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
      background: "#023950",
      // match with the menu
      borderRadius: state.isFocused ? "3px 3px 0 0" : 3,
      // Overwrittes the different states of border
      borderColor: state.isFocused ? "yellow" : "green",
      // Removes weird border around container
      boxShadow: state.isFocused ? null : null,
      "&:hover": {
        // Overwrittes the different states of border
        borderColor: state.isFocused ? "red" : "blue"
      }
    }),
    menu: base => ({
      ...base,
      // override border radius to match the box
      borderRadius: 0,
      // beautify the word cut by adding a dash see https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens for the compatibility
      hyphens: "auto",
      // kill the gap
      marginTop: 0,
      textAlign: "left",
      // prevent menu to scroll y
      wordWrap: "break-word"
    }),
    menuList: base => ({
      ...base,
      // kill the white space on first and last option
      padding: 0
    })
  };
```